# How can I print folder/sub-folders and import files from them?

Tags: python, list, file, directory

How can I print folder/sub-folder names and import files from each folder?

1.folder
1.1. folder
1.1.1.folder
1.1.1.1.folder
1.1.1.2.folder
1.1.2.folder
1.1.3.folder
1.2.folder
1.2.1.folder
1.2.2.folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.listdir() to get all files/folders in a directory and then loop over each and do the same recursively. Something like:

```py
import os
from queue import Queue

files = []

q = Queue()
q.put(PATH)

while not q.empty():
    path = q.get()
    
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isdir(file):
            print(file)
            q.put(file)
        else:
            files.append(file)
```

This would extract all files in each subdirectory to the `files` array and in the loop print each searched directory. Make sure to change `PATH` to your starting directory for the search.